# Matlab - Select Specific Row Based on Condition

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

```
points = [  
    -9.9043877608991468201413092380493, 426.34796945271797204125533010993, Maximum  
    -2.9714737944057521874892206269196, 422.13223302035451265143272598599, Minimum
    9.3758615553048990076305298649689, 441.87005169359418197397861057075, Maximum
]
```

I'd like to do loop through and create a new matrix with just the values where column three matches 'Maximum'.

When trying:

```
idx = ( points(:,3)=='Maximum' )
```

I get:

```
Maximum == Maximum
Minimum == Maximum
Maximum == Maximum
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the matrix points as is presented is not a valid matlab matrix unless Maximum is a number.
If that is the case then:

```
  idx=find( points(:,3)== Maximum  )
```

will give you the proper indices.

**Edit**

to obtain a new matrix with the values of "maximum" just

```
 new_matrix=points(idx,1:end-1)
```

Comment: `idx =

     1
     3`
is what I get in return. What exactly are those two values? I've tried making sense of it but I can't. Also, how can I turn the values matching "Maximum" in the 3rd column into a new matrix?